# Can't get Vulkan to work on a different user through sudo or SSH X11 Forwarding

Tags: vulkan

> Scenario and the problem:

I'm running two instances of the same Steam game on my main user X. To do that, I'm launching first instance on my main user and the other instance on another user. This works as I intended, but I can't get Vulkan to work on my second instance.

I'm running a second Steam instance from a different user with: `xhost local:remoto && sudo -u remoto /usr/games/steam -applaunch 1041320.` -> This works great using WINED3D. I'm trying to run it with Vulkan, because the game process will consumption about 50% less CPU with it.

> Troubleshooting:

To state that vulkan isn't working running through another user with sudo, I do: `xhost local:remoto && sudo -u remoto VK_LOADER_DEBUG=all vulkaninfo`

The output:

```
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
ERROR: setupLoaderTermPhysDevs:  Failed to detect any valid GPUs in the current config 
ERROR: setupLoaderTrampPhysDevs:  Failed during dispatch call of vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices' to lower layers or load
er to get count.
```

I tried to do the scenario above with SSH X11 Forwarding instead of sudo, but I got the exact same result.

The problem isn't Direct Rendering, since I'm running the game just fine with WINED3D with the above scenario.

Output of  `xhost local:remoto && sudo -u remoto glxinfo | grep "OpenGL renderer string"`:

```
non-network local connections being added to access control list
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Haswell Desktop
```

**Vulkan works fine if I run `VK_LOADER_DEBUG=all vulkaninfo` at the 'remoto' user Xsession.**

Comment: Vulkan is not compatible with X11 display forwarding because it does not interact with the display server like OpenGL does.